# Why do we do this.

Tags: rootscope, sessionstorage

I am unable to understand this code.

`$rootScope.loginbtn=$sessionStorage.loginbtn;
$rootScope.userName=$sessionStorage.userName;
$rootScope.admin=$sessionStorage.admin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given many details so an answer will be hard to give.

From what I can see though, $sessionStorage is a Angular service that acts as a wrapper for the inbuilt browser sessionStorage.

The code is making the login button, username and admin available on the $rootScope, presumably so they can be accessed in other controllers within the app.

Provide more details though, and we can give you a better answer